# Formatted TextField

Tags: javafx, textfield

I'm trying to create a `TextField` whose content is validated with a template. To do this, I create a `TextFormatter` to which I pass a `StringConverter`.

However, I do notice a weird thing about using `StringConverter<String>`. When I enter invalid data and the field loses focus, it does not clear its content (it only clears it after subsequent focusing). For comparison, when I use `StringConverter<LocalTime>` this problem is not noticed.

If I catch the change of focus and validate the data, the problem is solved, but I wonder why there is a discrepancy in the validation in both cases.

```
public class Sample extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField fieldA = new TextField();
        fieldA.setPromptText("00000");
        fieldA.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(String object) {
                if(object == null) return "";
                return object.matches("[0-9]{5}") ? object : "";
            }

            @Override
            public String fromString(String string) {
                if(string == null) return null;
                return string.matches("[0-9]{5}") ? string : null;
            }
        }));

//        fieldA.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
//            if(!fieldA.textProperty().getValueSafe().matches("[0-9]{5}")) {
//                fieldA.setText(null);
//            }
//        });

        TextField fieldB = new TextField();
        fieldB.setPromptText("HH:MM:SS");
        fieldB.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<LocalTime>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(LocalTime object) {
                if(object == null) return "";
                return object.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
            }

            @Override
            public LocalTime fromString(String string) {
                if(string == null) return null;
                return LocalTime.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
            }
        }));

        VBox vBox = new VBox(fieldA, fieldB);
        vBox.setSpacing(5);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

ps: note that the purpose is not to create a `TextField` that can only accept 5 numbers. This is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the discrepancy in behavior. The main problem is that updating controls is done by binding `valueProperty` (in `TextFormatter`) with `textProperty` (in `TextField`). Because notifications of change to all `Property` objects are only saturated when the value of the wrapper is changed, sequential *null* submission causes a one-time notification.

The different behavior when using `StringConverter<LocalTime>` is because `LocalTime::parse()` throws a `DateTimeParseException` exception in invalid formatting. This in turn leads to a new `valueProperty` value being set, and to a previous valid control value.

This is the specific snippet of `TextFormatter` that is responsible for this behavior.

```
void updateValue(String text) {
    if (!value.isBound()) {
        try {
            V v = valueConverter.fromString(text);
            setValue(v);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            updateText(); // Set the text with the latest value
        }
    }
}
```

And the solution to the problem is that implementing `StringConverter::fromString` with an invalid value, instead of returning *null*, should throw unchecked exceptions.

```
public class Sample extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField fieldA = new TextField();
        fieldA.setPromptText("00000");
        fieldA.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(String object) {
                if(object == null) return "";
                return object.matches("[0-9]{5}") ? object : "";
            }

            @Override
            public String fromString(String string) {
                if(string == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("Value is null");

                if(string.matches("[0-9]{5}")) {
                    return string;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("Value not match");
            }
        }));


        TextField fieldB = new TextField();
        fieldB.setPromptText("HH:MM:SS");
        fieldB.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<LocalTime>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(LocalTime object) {
                if(object == null) return "";
                return object.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
            }

            @Override
            public LocalTime fromString(String string) {
                if(string == null) return null;
                return LocalTime.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
            }
        }));


        VBox vBox = new VBox(fieldA, fieldB);
        vBox.setSpacing(5);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```